# Adding gradient in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the data I have:

```
    Model               Company MAE         MSE
1   Auto                Apple   1.188973    2.558698
2   (1,1,4) z dryfem    Apple   1.196080    2.546156
3   (2,1,3)             Apple   1.206834    2.594331
4   (4,1,1) z dryfem    Apple   1.199946    2.570619
5   Auto                Adobe   4.430002    32.033796
6   (0,1,4) z dryfem    Adobe   3.993517    30.139029
7   (2,1,3) z dryfem    Adobe   3.987862    29.867263
8   (2,1,2) z dryfem    Adobe   4.002413    30.266864
9   Auto                Microsoft   2.850063    12.607271
10  (0,1,5) z dryfem    Microsoft   2.709442    12.825030
11  (1,1,4) z dryfem    Microsoft   2.712788    12.746357
12  (5,1,0) z dryfem    Microsoft   2.695842    12.794361
```

I wanted to plot something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKXf0.png), but with changing intensity of alpha for every model type. I don't know how to do it. My code so far:

```
ggplot(data=modele_bledy, aes(x=MAE,y=MSE,colour=Company)) + geom_point(size=3,alpha=0.9 ) +facet_wrap(~Company,scales="free") +theme_fivethirtyeight() + theme(axis.title = element_text())
```

Comment: add `alpha = Model` inside the `aes()`

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to use a palette of similar colours instead of alpha? Some of the dots are barely visible.

Comment: ... you could try by setting the range of alpha via `scale_alpha(range = c(0.1, 1))`, i.e. increase the default `0.1` to make the points more visible.